# General notions of "basis" in algebra/model theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory

Free groups, free abelian groups, and vector spaces all have a notion of 'basis': a subset $B$ of the structure such that everything in the structure can be written uniquely as a finite combination of elements of $B$.

1. What is the most general (model theoretic) structure for which it makes sense to think about a basis?
2. Do all of these structures have theorems along the lines of "if $S$ is a structure with a basis and $T$ is a substructure, then $T$ must also have a basis"? This certainly is true for free (abelian) groups and vector spaces.

Comment: I imagine a minimal [with respect to inclusion] set $A$ such that the closure of $A$ is the entire model; or alternatively, a maximal set of elements such that no element is in the substructure (or "sufficiently elementary submodel" perhaps) generated by the other elements of the set. But those are idle speculations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion of basis can be generalized in multiple ways. The way it seems like you're thinking of - a basis for a structure $A$ is a subset $S\subseteq A$ such that every element of $A$ can be expressed uniquely (in some sense) as a term using parameters from $S$ - is more a notion of universal algebra than of model theory: Look into [free algebras.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object)

In this reading of the question, the answer to (2) is no. For example, consider the free monoid on one generator. This is isomorphic to $\langle \mathbb{N}, 0, +\rangle$, and $\{1\}$ is a basis. Now consider the submonoid with domain $\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1\}$. This submonoid is generated by $2$ and $3$, and it's not hard to see that any generating set must contain $2$ and $3$. But no generating set is a basis, since $6$ can be written as $2+2+2$ or as $3+3$.

Another way to generalize is the abstract notion of a [matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid). Matroids also get involved in model theory, though model theorists tend to call their matroids "pregeometries". There are various natural closure operators that you can associate to models of a complete first-order theory $T$, the most prominent being algebraic closure, [acl](http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Definable_and_algebraic_closure). Under certain conditions, these closure operators will satisfy the matroid axioms, giving rise to notions of basis and dimension for models of $T$. For example, in a [strongly minimal theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_minimal_theory), acl gives a pregeometry - in the theory of $k$-vector spaces, acl is Span and the dimension is linear dimension, while in the theory of algebraically closed fields, $\text{acl}(X)$ is the algebraic closure of the field generated by $X$ and the dimension is transcendence degree.

In the model-theoretic situation, sometimes the existence of a nice pregeometry is guaranteed by elementary properties of the theory (for example, the property of being strongly minimal), and then an *elementary* substructure of a structure with a basis will still have a basis (since it shares the pregeometry).